# Debugging crash during app exit (WPF)

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-debugging

I'm trying to figure out why an WPF-app won't exit imediately on closing it. Using Process Explorer I hade found out that WerFault.exe is started while exiting which seem to indicate that something crashes during the teardown, perhaps some destructor or dispose that fails. This started happening when I recently switched to VS2015. I am running Windows 8.

My question is: How can I find out what the real problem is? Any way of finding a crash log for WerFault.exe? I have hundreds of destructors and dispose-methods so it's a bit hard to put breakpoints in all of them. Any other way of capturing these kinds of errors in VS?

The exit code is -1073740791 which "indicate a bug in the executed software that causes stack overflow, leading to abnormal termination of the software". But where?

Some more info from the event log:

Faulting module name: ucrtbase.DLL, version: 10.0.10240.16390, time stamp: 0x55a5b718

Exception code: 0xc0000409

Fault offset: 0x0000000000065a4e

[image]

Comment: Have you tried JIT debugging? Is there Debugger value under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AeDebug`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try enabling [user mode dumps](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787181%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

1. Create the registry key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Windows Error Reporting\LocalDumps`
2. Within `LocalDumps`, create a key that is the name of your executable
3. Within the key you just created, set the values of `DumpFolder`, `DumpCount`, `DumpType`, and `CustomDumpFlags` as needed (you should definitely set `DumpType` to 2 for full dumps, otherwise I don't think that enough information will be captured to debug a managed dump).

Once you have done this, whenever your executable crashes a dump file will be created in the folder specified by `DumpFolder` (or `%LOCALAPPDATA%\CrashDumps` by default).